# Сохранение ссылки после перехода на авторизацию

Tags: php, yii2

Yii2. Доступ к системе имеют только авторизованные юзеры, контролируется behaviors в контроллерах. Если юзер открывает внутреннюю ссылку будучи не авторизованным, то его перекидывает на главную страницу, где есть авторизация. - Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы его введенная ссылка не терялась при этом, а записывалась, скажем, в сессию? Ну, и при авторизации редиректил бы на нее, а не на дефолтную..

Answer (score 2):

Если мне не изменяет память в Yii2 есть метод для этого `goBack`, после авторизации обращаетесь к нему, или можно смотреть реферрер и если он есть сначала отправлять человека туда, потом уже пробовать метод:

```
$backUrl = Yii::$app->request->referrer;     

if(!is_null($backUrl)){     

   return $this->redirect($backUrl);

}

else{   

  return $this->goBack(); 

}
```

Comment: А `$return_url` откуда взяли?

Comment: @Visman исправил